# mainting the order in redis with zet and set

Tags: redis, phpredis

I have a bookings which are stored in hash
HSET bookings booking_id "1",booking_info .. ..

and have a zset  with timestamp as a score and value as a booking_id these are the booking create date
 e.g zet create_date
i also have a 4 types of sets which have a status as per the bookings set with values as booking_ids
e.g
bookings:pending values booking_ids
bookings:confirmed values booking_ids
and the last one is the same as zet with bookings which contains 
zset deadline_date of the booking.

So now i need to show the bookings which are confirmed and having a create date range from date 1 to date 2 and with deadline date from date 1 to date 2
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To me, there a few possible options for approaching the problem depending on how much of the processing you want to defer to Redis (or not).  Your basic steps are:

- Identify the booking IDs that have a creation date in the desired range.  The tag on the question indicates you're using `phpredis`, so you can probably get this with `zRangeByScore`.
- Do the same to identify the IDs that have a deadline date in the desired range.
- Identify the booking IDs that are confirmed.  Based on your question description, this is already stored in Redis as a set.

The task now is to identify the booking IDs that exist in all three sets.  You can:

- Yank the booking IDs out of Redis and determine the common IDs in PHP.  `zRangeByScore` should already retrieve arrays representing the booking IDs falling in the proper ranges for creation date as well as deadline, and `sMembers` can get you an array containing all the booking IDs from the confirmed set.
- Alternately, you can push all of the booking IDs retrieved by the results of `zRangeByScore` back into Redis as a set using `sAdd`.  You could then get Redis to give you the intersection between this set and the confirmed bookings set with `sInter`, which should return an array of booking IDs satisfying all of these criteria.  If you go this route, you will probably want to remember to delete whichever set you created to hold all of the IDs satisfying the creation date and deadline conditions.

Either way, once you get all of the IDs you can retrieve the booking information associated with each ID using `hGet`.

Comment: thanks for your promt answer.
i will try this
can you give me how to use zinterstore by phpredis.
i am not able to figure out how to use as its not in the document of phpredis.

Comment: @nick It is named `zInter` in `phpredis`.  https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#zinter

Comment: thankyou one last question ....
can the above suggestion you given can maintain the ordering ? how ?
e.g order by deadline date or order by create date or order by booking id

Comment: @nick I'm assuming that you will want to dynamically support different sorting criteria.  Once again, you have the option to do that sorting in PHP outside of Redis (you can use `zScore` to yank down the deadline date or creation date for each ID) prior to retrieving booking information with `hGet` for each ID.  I suppose you could also write the search result IDs back into a temporary sorted set in Redis with the appropriate date as the score and then retrieve them all, but that seems like overkill (it is an option however).

Comment: i understood your e.g and works well.
but a little confused on the point of sorting and limit..
since its outside redis how will i query with limit ? e.g 25 per page or pagination

can you please help me with an small e.g will be of great help